# TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not iterable in python

Tags: python, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to create a pdf from html page using xhtml2pdf.. While Converting this, my terminal shows following Error Message..

What does error TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not iterable mean?

How can i prevent this? following sample code is am using....to convert a pdf

```
 <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   @page 
    {
     @top-right 
     {
      content: "Page " counter(page);
     }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

and also am using Following command line for pdf conversion..

```
xhtml2pdf test.html test.pdf
```

In that conversion i'm getting a error as i said early. what can i do for that ?

Comment: Mind showing us what exactly you do and what appears on the screen?

Comment: What does error TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not iterable mean?

Comment: The error means some method or function returned `NotImplemented` and the code calling it assumed it returns a list or some other iterable object.  I suspect the question you're really asking is 'why is my code not working?', and this is impossible to answer without any code and without the full traceback of the exception.

Comment: Hey @LukeWoodward i gave a sample html code

Comment: The code you have posted goes no way at all to helping you.  Somewhere in your Python code you are calling xhtml2pdf, right?  Please add that code to the question.  And as I said before, please also include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: @Luke Woodward Please look up my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in xhtml2pdf.

The traceback I get when I run your command-line is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\xhtml2pdf-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('xhtml2pdf==0.0.6', 'console_scripts', 'xhtml2pdf')()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\pisa.py", line 146, in command
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\pisa.py", line 363, in execute
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\document.py", line 89, in pisaDocument
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\document.py", line 57, in pisaStory
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\parser.py", line 685, in pisaParser
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\context.py", line 498, in parseCSS
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py", line 434, in parse
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py", line 533, in _parseStylesheet
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py", line 654, in _parseAtKeyword
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\xhtml2pdf\w3c\cssParser.py", line 758, in _parseAtPage
TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object is not iterable
```

Digging into the code a bit, it seems the problem is around here, in `w3c/cssParser.py`

```python
        if src.startswith('@'):
            # @media, @page, @font-face
            src, atResults = self._parseAtKeyword(src)
            if atResults is not None:
                stylesheetElements.extend(atResults)   # this is line 758
```

`_parseAtKeyword(src)` returns a 2-tuple containing `src` and `NotImplemented` for any CSS at-keyword it doesn't recognise, in particular, for `@top-right`.  This then causes the `extend` in the following line to fail, as `NotImplemented` isn't a valid argument to `extend`.

`@top-right` isn't familiar to me, and I couldn't find any Google search results for `css @top-right`.  If I replace `@top-right` with `@topright`, I got the same behaviour, and if I replaced `@top-right` with `top-right`, the code appeared to enter an infinite loop.  So I'm not particularly impressed with xhtml2pdf's CSS parser.

Replacing line 757 with

```python
            if atResults is not None and atResults is not NotImplemented:
```

appears to get xhtml2pdf working enough to convert your test document to a PDF.  However, the output it generates might not be what you hope for.

I suspect the best thing to do here would be to post on the [xhtml2pdf mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/xhtml2pdf).